# SvelteKit preloadData 2 times on the same page

Tags: sveltekit

I have a page that has links to 2 different pages. If I call the preloadData function just once, everything works fine and it does the routing instantly. But if I do 2 preloadData, it stops working, and when doing the routing, it asks for the data again. I can't find anything in the documentation that says it can only be called once per page

```js
//works
onMount(() => {
    preloadData('/page1');
});
```

```js
//it does not work
onMount(() => {
    preloadData('/page1');
    preloadData('/page2');
});
```

Is there any way that I can preload the data for 2 pages at a time?

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway? Links start pre-loading as soon as the user hovers them. Login and "about" pages usually do not have that much data.

Comment: I put about and login as an example. I actually have links to two pages that have a lot of data, and I want the navigation to be a little faster